# return lines of multiple files iteratively

Tags: python

Let us say I have a dictionary containing the file names and fullnames of 3 text files, all of the same number of lines, N.

```
dof = {'myf1':'/a/b/myf1.txt', 'myf2':'/a/b/myf2.txt', 'myf3':'/a/b/myf3.txt'}
```

What'd be the most efficient/pythonic way to iterate over all files, each line as follows:

```
line 1 of file 1, then line 1 of file 2, then line 1 of file 3;
line 2 of file 1, then line 2 of file 2, then line 2 of file 3;
...
line N of file 1, then line N of file 2, then line N of file 3;
```

A general solution for any number of files in the dictionary and any number of total lines would be preferable.

Comment: what is the order of the files ? The lexical order of the keys of the dict ? (there is no guarantee on the order of the items in a dict in python as far as I remember, so you should clarify what `file 1` means exactly.

Comment: @AndreHolzner good point, the numbers could have perfectly been letters, the order is given by the keys you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip()` to iterate over the lines in triples:

```
for line1, line2, line3 in zip(openfile1, openfile2, openfile3):
```

You could produce the open file handles with:

```
files = [open(dof[name]) for name in sorted(dof)]

for lines in zip(*files):
```

where `lines` is a tuple of strings, the next line of each of the input files.

If the input files do *not* have the same number of lines, you can use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead to provide a replacement value for those lines missing (use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3).

Comment: what happens if not all files have the same number of lines ?

Comment: @AndreHolzner: then the extra lines are ignored.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, looks like a great suggestion, just as a short follow up, how do i make it generic for the dictionary I have and any number of files?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are the samurai of python! thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am opening ~ 48 files at the same time, I get a memory error, is it trying to open all files into memory?

Comment: @Dnaiel: Ore you on Python 2? Then use `itertools.izip()` instead of `zip()` to handle iterators better.

Comment: @Dnaiel: `from itertools import izip`, then `for lines in izip(*files):`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow, nice! u re indeed the samurai! yes, I am in python 2.7